# SQL - Running Comma separated list dynamically and returning rows depending on the value passed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
TL_TCT_Id
3,8
3,4
3,8
3,8
3,8
3,8
3,8
3,8
```

TL_TCT_Id is string (nvarchar(100))

And i have this script that passes lets say 8 but no results are being pulled out

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetComponentByIndex]
@index int
AS
BEGIN


WITH temporaryTable as
(SELECT ('''' + replace(TL_TCT_Id, ',', ''',''') + '''') as [TCT]
FROM TL_TemplateLayout)

select * from temporaryTable t
where cast(8 as nvarchar) in (t.TCT)

END
```

What is going wrong with this statement?
How can i fix this so i get some results from the table?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want all rows containing `8` to be returned?

Comment: @Arun Palanisamy All the results from TL_TCT_Id apart from 3,4

Comment: Since all your rows are string you cannot use `IN` to check for specific value. For e.g., `'3','8'` is considered as a single value.

Comment: The *better* answer here is fix your design. Don't store multiple (delimited) values in a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator IN does not help in this case.
Use LIKE:

```
select * 
from TL_TemplateLayout 
where concat(',', [TL_TCT_Id], ',') like concat('%,', 8, ',%')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdae7c4a2652df60a7d3f3f7c1b20073).
Results:

```
> | TL_TCT_Id |
> | :-------- |
> | 3,8       |
> | 3,8       |
> | 3,8       |
> | 3,8       |
> | 3,8       |
> | 3,8       |
> | 3,8       |
```